# Python Numpy 2D plot set total number of y-tics with autoscaling

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I would like to limit the total number of tics on the y-axis in a 2D plot. In the example image provided you can see that the `F_X` plot has 6 total tics (0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1) while the `F_Y` plot has 8. Is there a way to still have the axis scale automatically but fix the number of total tics as the plots with greater than 6 tics in my example look too busy?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ax.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=num)`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.locator_params) is the easiest way to do this.

`nbins` will set the *maximum* number of bins (i.e. spaces between the ticks) for each axis.  "Even" numbers will still be chosen, but this value controls the density of ticks on an axis.  The default value for a new axes is 9 (in other words, a maximum of 10 ticks/ticklabels).

For example, let's set up something that will look rather busy by default:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1977)

# Generate some data with different ranges
x = np.linspace(0, 8.8, 1000)
ydata = np.random.normal(0, 1, (4, x.size)).cumsum(axis=1)
ydata *= np.array([1e-3, 1e3, 10, 1e-2])[:,None]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4)
for y, ax in zip(ydata, axes):
    ax.plot(x, y, color='salmon')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Oy!!  Not so good! Let's see if we can do better:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4)
for y, ax in zip(ydata, axes):
    ax.plot(x, y, color='salmon')
    ax.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Getting there, but still a bit busy.  We could reduce `nbins` further, but we'll quickly wind up with almost no ticks.  Instead, one trick I like to use is to "prune" the first and last ticks from the axes.  This can also be controlled by `locator_params`:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4)
for y, ax in zip(ydata, axes):
    ax.plot(x, y, color='salmon')
    ax.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=5, prune='both')
plt.show()
```

[image]

This "pruning" is even more effective when combined with shared x-axes, in the case of the type of plot you're making.  The main effect for this post is to turn off some of the x-ticklabels.  However, this will also link the interactive zooming and panning of all axes so that the x-range is shared:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, sharex=True)
for y, ax in zip(ydata, axes):
    ax.plot(x, y, color='salmon')
    ax.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=5, prune='both')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now we can move things a bit closer together:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, sharex=True)
for y, ax in zip(ydata, axes):
    ax.plot(x, y, color='salmon')
    ax.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=5, prune='both')

fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Finally, in this particular case, you might also consider using [`ax.margins(...)`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins) to add some padding in the y-direction and force "tight" scaling of the data range in the x-direction.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, sharex=True)
for y, ax in zip(ydata, axes):
    ax.plot(x, y, color='salmon')
    ax.margins(x=0, y=0.05)
    ax.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=5, prune='both')

fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is an absolutely stunning answer.

Comment: @MattStokes - Happy to help! i.m.o. `locator_params` and `margins` are the two most under-advertised but incredibly useful features of matplotlib.